# How to add a class to an html element when a web page has been scrolled several px

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to add a class to $ ('# header') when my web page scrolls down by 100px
this is the code :

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var offset = $(window).offset();
if (offset.top > 100) {
    $('#header').addClass('header2')
}
else {
    $('#header').removeClass('header2')
};
});
```

#JQueryCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below mention code

```html
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
     //console.log(scroll);
    if (scroll >= 50) {
        //console.log('a');
        $("#header").addClass("header2");
    } else {
        //console.log('a');
        $("#header").removeClass("header2");
    }
});
```